# How to provide the U-Boot default environment from a file in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, xilinx, bitbake, u-boot

I want to avoid setting the default environment in `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS`, therefore I've set `CONFIG_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE="uEnv.txt"` and created that text file but bitbake doesn't find it:

`make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'uEnv.txt', needed by 'include/generated/defaultenv_autogenerated.h'.  Stop.`

This is what the tree and the files look like:

```
└── u-boot
    ├── files
    │   ├── ma1.cfg
    │   └── uEnv.txt
    └── u-boot-xlnx_%.bbappend
```

ma1.cfg:

```
CONFIG_USE_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE="uEnv.txt"
```

u-boot-xlnx_%.bbappend:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI_append_tmc = " \
    file://ma1.cfg \
    file://uEnv.txt \
    "

PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN += "${PN}-env"
RPROVIDES_${PN}-env += "u-boot-default-env"
```

I don't know where to put the `uEnv.txt` so it will be found. I already (blindly) tried to specify some different paths like `CONFIG_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE="../uEnv.txt"` but to no avail. I suspect that I need to put it somewhere in a `do_configure_append()` but I don't know where.

Searching for `CONFIG_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE` only yields results which state *that* it can be used to create the environment from a file[1], but unfortunately not *how*. Or, more precisely: How to use it with bitbake.

So I hope someone can help me here: What do I need to do so bitbake places the text file where make is going to find it?

[1] https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2018-March/323347.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `uEnv.txt` file to the build directory to be found by Make.

You can do this in your bbappend file like:

```
do_configure_append() {
    cp ${WORKDIR}/uEnv.txt ${S}
}
```

Comment: I had to change it to the new syntax do_configure:append